# Price Field Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

There will be a form field for which it will be always displayed in the form "zzzzzzz.zz".
As example if form field is 5, it will be displayed as 5.00;  if form field is 005, it will be displayed as 5.00;  if form field is spaces, it will be displayed as null entry. Ever change will be on "onBlur".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's no need to SHOUT here. It won't get you help any faster, and SHOUTING at people is quite rude. There's also no need to repeat tag information in your title; the tag system works quite well at organizing questions into proper categories and getting the attention of people interested in those tags. Thanks.  You've also done a fine job of stating your requirements (what it should do), but haven't provided any of your efforts to actually do it yourself. Please [edit] your question and post what you've tried so far, and explain how it isn't working for you. Thanks.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: i need the help regarding to solve this price field validation issue.

Comment: We all know that you need help. That's why you're here to ask. No need to tell us, and no need to shout. Stop it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/c7YPH/1/

```
$("#foo").blur(function() {
    $(this).val(Number($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

also, the above requires you source jquery and have this within a $(document).ready.

jquery will be a good idea if you plan to do much js... but with plain js: http://jsfiddle.net/c7YPH/2/

```
document.getElementById("foo").onblur=function(){ 
    this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(2);
};
```

Comment: hi dear friend smerny, yeah it's working here. But i don't know jquery & want to use simple logics of javascript. I have tried with the following javascript code & calling it from the html with onBlur. But don't know why its not working. Can u look after this issue. 

 
function doValueCheck() {
 var test = document.forms[0].test.value;
 test=test.toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById("test").value = test;
 return false;
}

Comment: jquery really makes things simpler, not more difficult.